# XMLHTTPRequest Parse Webpage Text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am creating a chrome extension and part of it needs to parse through the current webpages text to find price, quantity, and item name of a product. I am struggling to implement this and have tried to start over several times.
1. Is xmlhttprequest the way to go if I am parsing text? Or will regex be ok?
2. I have been using xmlhttprequest. Once I have the webpage URL stored, I need to parse the webpage for price, quantity, and item name. How do I do this dynamically? In other words how do I implement this psuedocode:
"go through current pages text
find price (for example, by looking for the '$' character)
find quantity
find item name
store values in popup.html"

Do I need to parse the responseText instead? If I do, how can I set it up to look for a specific character?

I apologize if I did not follow any SO rules, this is my second post, and if I did something wrong I would be more than happy to correct it. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're asking for an off site resources (`xmlhttprequest`  vs `regex`), which is off topic. Also, your question is broad. Please show us what you've tried and where you got stuck. Last, look through the help center on [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: 1) XHR can return a `Document`, there are lots of examples, try searching 2) regex would be useful only to extract the price out of a DOM element's text